# JQuery can't read the innerHTML of a table row created by AngularJS' ng-repeat (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add a hover effect on table rows when the mouse enters the rows. For this i am using JQuery and the on()-Method. The table is created with AngularJS' ng-repeat.

On Firefox everything works fine. When i enter the row, for example the color changes.
On IE8 JQuery isn't able to resolve the AngularJS attributes in the table rows with td. With table headers it works fine.

```
<table class="testClass" id="searchTextResults">
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="item in friends[0].Order">
                {{item}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
            <td ng-repeat="item in friend.Order">
                {{friend[item]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the content of the innerHTML in IE8 when i alert it:
"ngRepeat: item in friend.Order"

I also tried to include JSON2.0 and tried the document.createElement() solution
but nothing worked.

Here is the small testscript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".testClass tr").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (event) {
       alert(this.innerHTML);
   });
});
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: it returns the same content. but the html in there isn't the important part. it just helps me to see if there is any content. i think the title is a bit confusing. sorry. i want to archieve a background-color hover effect on the rows. later then with transition. the ie8 doesn't support it, so i wanted to solve it with jquery.

Comment: use css hover then...

Comment: the problem is, that ie8 doesn't support transition. hover without transition would be the last solution. or is it possible to create a animated hover effect with css?

Comment: what sort of transition you want?

Comment: i want a fadeOut/fadeIn when the filter of AngularJS hides the entries

Comment: have you tried fadetoggle & animate?

Comment: in css3 you can use transition, and in css, you CAN hide&show the element on hover, but it won't be smooth!

Comment: the problem is that the fades, animations etc work in firefox but not in ie. ie isn't able to resolve the AngularJS attributes or something like that. the problem is somewhere between ie and AngularJS.

Comment: IE has problems with everything and everyone! sometimes fadein, fadeout doesn't work in ie but fadetoggle works, I know, the wonders of IE! give css a shot then [http://jsfiddle.net/tbTBL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/tbTBL/1/) whatever effect you want , you can give it, but like I said, it won't be all that smooth...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do some effect or animation on the row. You would do this with a directive, not standard jQuery. When doing things the Angular way, dom manipulation is ONLY done in directives.

http://jsfiddle.net/engZB/

```
app.directive("animateHover", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).on("mouseenter", function() {
                $(this).find("td").css("background-color","blue");
                //Anything you want to do with the elements here
            });
            $(element).on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).find("td").css("background-color","");
                //Anything you want to do with the elements here
            });
        }
    }
});

<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" animate-hover>
    <td ng-repeat="item in friend.Order">
        {{friend[item]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```